# SignalR - Unhandled Rejection (Error): WebSocket closed with status code: 1000 ()

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

An asp.net core application with react+redux on the client side, using signalR.
Getting the following error on the client side:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): WebSocket closed with status code: 1000 ().
```

Seems like this is a "[normal closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent)", but there's no code to close the connection.

The application sends small images at 60 FPS per viewport, in several viewports. This utilizes the JS thread almost completely, to the extent that I'd assume that it may prevent signalR from maintaining keep-alive.

Tried setting the timeouts in the server for signalR to their max value, that did not prevent the issue from recurring.

What is it that could cause the signalR socket to close without invoking the close and without an error message?

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue, I turned on the [logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-5.0) as Jesper [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66548642/388190).
The issue was that I was cancelling a CancellationToken passed to the [SendAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.clientproxyextensions.sendasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) method. For some odd reason cancelling the send closes the socket (I'd expect it to only cancel the specific message, not close the connection).

Comment: Are you sure that token wasn't being sent somewhere else too?

Comment: @Jesper, I also sent the cancellation token to the loop that fetches images. Why would that be an issue?

The code is sort of like this (where _cts is a CancellationTokenSource):
`var images = _imageProvider(_cts.Token); await foreach (var image in images) { await SendImage(image, _cts.Token); }`

Comment: That shouldn't do anything. I was more concerned with it being passed to setup methods, since if it was reused it would cancel everything it's been passed to. This seems obvious but I've seen people create one shared CancellationTokenSource "for convenience", pass the same token everywhere, then cancel something and wonder why everything everywhere is going down.

Comment: Maybe the way a send is cancelled is by tearing down the connection in some sort of nuke-from-orbit approach. It's hard to retract network I/O. And the CancellationToken model of cancellation often involves throwing OperationCanceledException, which has a habit of bubbling up to other places.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the browser or the server could close out of self-preservation or reaching set limits.

- Most likely: [The default maximum size of a hub message (`MaximumReceiveMessageSize`) is 32 KB, and a image could easily surpass this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options). You could turn on `EnableDetailedErrors` to see if there's more info.
- If the browser is unable to send quickly enough, it will need to buffer and this buffer can't grow infinitely. You could also run into some sort of anti-malware protection based either on hogging the JS thread (maybe use workers?) or on using too much network I/O. The server can also close for similar reasons.

<del>As for why the error message is vague: [The browser literally can't give you too much feedback about this - see the warning text before 9.3.4](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#feedback-from-the-protocol).</del> Edit: this is wrong and only applies to close code 1006.

Comment: Thank you! I tried increasing the MaximumReceiveMessageSize to int.MaxValue, but it did not help. About the warning message before 9.3.4 - it says: "In all of these cases, the WebSocket connection close code would be 1006", for some reason, in my case the code is 1000

Comment: @Tom Good eye, just spotted that myself. Turn on as much logging as you can in the ASP.NET Core application and it will hopefully say something about closing the connection.

Comment: The logs helped me solve the issue, so +1.